# Android - Reduce Code in OnCreate to avoid Black Screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity.Let's call it as Activity A. Clicking on a button in this activity sends data to a server ( a POST method) and also launches Activity B.

Since there is some computation involved before sending data to the server from Activity A, I have implemented the task of sending data to server as a Async task.

In Activity B, in OnCreate method there is a GET request which gets fired. So as a result when Activity B launches, this GET request gets  fired. After getting data from the server I load the data in the list view. All these are in the OnCreate method. Again, I have implemented this GET request as a async task.

Also, the POST method in Activity A and the GET method in Activity B are inter-related.

The issue  I am facing is  when I click the button in Activity A, the screen goes black and appears after 10 seconds (Activity B) . I have implemented a progress bar in Activity B and made it to appear till I get a response from the server. But this does not appear at all. All I am getting is suddenly the listview getting populated.

Wondering why this appears as the task is an async task in Activity A and B

```
Activity B

   onCreate method
{

    display progress bar

    asynctask to fetch data

    while(data not fetched){

      // loop through until you get data            

    }

    populate list view  

}
```

Could any one please let me know where I am going wrong. This is the minimal code which need to be there in the oncreate method. Also, since this  is a one time activity I do not want to implement this as a service. Also, I wish not to go with splash screen. All I want is the progress bar to get displayed till I get the data from the server. Kindly help to avoid this black screen when going from Activity A to Activity B.

Thanks

Comment: while(data not fetched){ ? really ? what's the point of the asynctask if you just stand there waiting for it to finish?

Comment: If the data is not available, the list view will not be populated. hence I need to wait till the list view is populated. Any suggestions how to avoid this scenario. Thanks

Comment: that's what onPostExecute is for. for executing stuff after the task is complete

Comment: Thanks for this. I will implement this and let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could any one please let me know where I am going wrong.

The `while(data not fetched){}` bit is most likely the source of your difficulty.

Kicking off a task in `onCreate()` is fine. However, *do not block processing of the rest of `onCreate()`*. Delete the `while` loop, and have work in your task's `onPostExecute()` handle updating the UI when the data is ready.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just an affirmation. Do I need to cut the code while(data not fetched){

      // loop through until you get data            

    }

    populate list view  and paste it in onPostExecute() method. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: @TimothyRajan: Since all you provided is pseudocode, I cannot really answer that. I will repeat: **do not block processing of the rest of `onCreate()`**.

Comment: Thanks for this Commonsware. I will implement this and let you know the outcome.